# bufferedwritter writing weird foreign characters?

Tags: java, bufferedwriter

I'm writing a little program that just takes a file, and trims the last 4 characters after a space and writes those to a new file. When I tell it to do this and then print them to console it works fine. They show up fine and everything works. But when I use the BufferedWriter to write it to a new file it gives me a weird string of characters in that file when I check it. Here is my code:

```
package trimmer;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class trimmer {

private File file;
private File newfile;

private Scanner in;

public void Create() {

    String temp, temp1;

    try {

        setScanner(new Scanner(file));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("file not found!!");

    }

    if (!newfile.exists()) {
        try {
            newfile.createNewFile();
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(newfile.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            while (in.hasNextLine()) {
                temp1 = in.nextLine();
                temp = temp1.substring(temp1.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1);
                System.out.println(temp);
                bw.write(temp);
            }
            bw.close();
            System.out.println("done!");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not make new file: " + newfile + " Error code: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}

public Scanner getScanner() {
    return in;
}

public void setScanner(Scanner in) {
    this.in = in;
}

public File getFile() {
    return file;
}

public void setFile(File file) {
    this.file = file;
}

public File getNewfile() {
    return newfile;
}

public void setNewfile(File newfile) {
    this.newfile = newfile;
}

}
```

and when I check the file it looks like this:

```
䐳噔吳商吳啍唳噎吳剄唳剄䘳剄唳噎吳商䠳卉䌳䕎䜳䱁䠳卉䴳㉕倳乓䐳䍐䐳啐吳䍖吳乓吳啍䔳䥘䌳噔匳剕唳乓唳䅍䌳䕎䜳䱁䴳㉕倳乓䐳䍐䐳啐吳䍖䠳卉吳乓吳啍䔳䥘䌳噔匳剕唳乓唳䅍
```

Can anyone tell me why this would be happening?

Comment: Which file are you passing to file variable?

Comment: What is your default encoding and what is the encoding of the file you're reading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FileWriter uses the platform default character encoding.  If this is not the encoding that you want, then you need to use an OutputStreamWriter with the appropriately chosen character encoding.